# Why would uniqueness validation fail for unique records?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm populating a Rails 3.2 app with initial data. I have a Country and a State model. In the State model I have

```
  validates :country_id,
    presence: true

  validates :name,
    presence: true,
    uniqueness: {
      scope: :country_id
    }
```

When I try to create a state I'm getting

```
State Exists (0.9ms)  SELECT 1 FROM "states" WHERE ("states"."name" = 'my-test-state' AND "states"."country_id" = 220) LIMIT 1
  Country Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "countries".* FROM "countries" WHERE "countries"."id" = 220 LIMIT 1
   (0.6ms)  ROLLBACK
```

Thing is, there are only 4 records in the State model, none of which are identical to the onle I'm trying to create. This is definitely a unique record.

Why would the validation fail? Is my syntax correct for validating on two columns? (name + country_id)

Thanks

Comment: are you sure your constraints in the DB level are correct? What you are doing seems ok to me...

Comment: It doesn't matter to Rails what constraints are on the db side. It does a select and if it finds any records that violate the uniqueness constraint then it is invalid.

Comment: Are you sure it's invalid for the reason you think it is? What happens if you create a new uniquely invalid object in the console and type `object.valid? && object.errors`?

Comment: thanks everyone for the ideas. you are correct, it was not this validation causing the record to be not saved, but another issue elsewhere. I mistook the 'State Exists' header in my logs to be a warning, but it is simply a note that the validation is being run. Managed to get everything running after a bit of digging around. Thanks